# Combine Room and Content Resolver data into one object

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-room, android-architecture-components

My app supports adding contacts to a note.

In this process, I'm storing a `Contact` entity in my apps database, where I primarily use the `contactId` to identify the contact.

In my UI, the name should be displayed, too. Therefore, I'm looking for a possibility to create a combined query (like a `INNER JOIN`) for fetching my apps contact data together with the name of the contact from the device's address book.

Is this possible?

My contact entity:

```
data class Contact(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Contacts.COL_ID) val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Contacts.COL_CONTACT_ID) val contactId: Long,
    /* This should be fetched from the content provider. */ val contactName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Contacts.COL_TRANSACTION_ID) val transactionId: Long
) : Model
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Is this possible?" -- no, sorry. However, you could have a repository object work with both your `RoomDatabase` and a `ContentResolver`. The repository would expose an API for working with domain models that combine data from your Room entities and your `ContentResolver`-supplied `Cursor` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fetch data using single inner join from your app DB and contacts of the phone.
You need to retrieve both of them separately. After retrieving them, combine the results.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well, my current strategy was to fetch all data from the app's db and ignore the name, which is added afterwards. So I'm simply looping over the list to add all missing names. Is there a better strategy or 'best practice' for combining the two pieces?

Comment: Maybe, you can get your desired names from the contacts than stored these names within your local DB.
It's a way around.